# Impresión de firma capturada en VB.net

Tags: vb.net, impresion

> Estoy capturando una firma en un picture box y cuando la llamo para la impresión en Crystal Report, la misma sale muy clara.
> Como lo puedo corregir? Oscurecer?

Comment: Y la respuesta sería: oscureciéndola. Exacto, así de sencillo. Sin el código es la única respuesta que se te puede dar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.